# how to delete a specific object from array object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

mycode is look like below:-

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52a02251305157fe20ce140f"),
  "cats" : [
          {
                  "catname" : "elect",
                  "disname" : "Elect",
                  "subcats" : [
                          {
                                  "subcatname" : "mobile",
                                  "subdisname" : "Mobiles"
                          },
                          {
                                  "subcatname" : "cam",
                                  "subdisname" : "Cam"
                          }
                  ]
          }
  ]
  }
```

I Want To Delete mobile from subcats i am trying like below:-

```
 db.demo.update({"cats.catname":"elect"},{$pull: {"subcats.$.subcatname":"mobile"}},  {"upsert":true})
```

After Delete mobile code look like below(i Expected like below):-

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("52a02251305157fe20ce140f"),
  "cats" : [
          {
                  "catname" : "elect",
                  "disname" : "Elect",
                  "subcats" : [
                          {
                                  "subcatname" : "cam",
                                  "subdisname" : "Cam"
                          }
                  ]
          }
    ]
    }
```

Best Regards 
GSY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not

```
{$pull: {"subcats.$.subcatname":"mobile"}}
```

but

```
{$pull: {"cats.$.subcats":{"subcatname":"mobile"}}
```

>

```
db.demo.update({"cats.catname":"elect"},{$pull: {"cats.$.subcats":{"subcatname":"mobile"}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it by using **$pull** operator. Query should be as follows :

```
db.myObject.update(
    {"cats.catname" : "elect"},
    {$pull:{"cats.$.subcats" : {subcatname : "mobile"}}}
);
```